# Devexpress gridcontrol excel

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to export gridcontrol excell but I have some float values but when I export it it is exporting like text 
I am using this code:

```
 gridControl1.ExportToXlsx("D:\\Turnover.xls");
```

after that I searched some and I found something:

```
 GridViewExportLink link;
       var provider = new ExportXlsProvider(fileName:@"D:\Trunover.xls");

        link = gridView1.CreateExportLink(provider) as GridViewExportLink;
        link.ExportCellsAsDisplayText = false;
        link.ExportTo(true);
```

but on `link.ExportTo(true);` it is erroring mee this:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to bother with the GridViewExportLink. In fact, per the Export To XLS documentation:

> Printing links (in WinForms and WPF) do not support this [Excel]
>   export mode and to use the data-aware export, it is required to call
>   the corresponding methods of specific controls (e.g., GridControl).

You can simply specify an [XlsExportOptions object](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingXlsExportOptions_ctortopic) with the GridControl's [ExportToXls method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ExportToXlstopic):

```
string FileName = "C:\\myfile.xls";
gridControl1.ExportToXls(FileName, new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.XlsExportOptions(DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextExportMode.Value));
```